# Crawled properties doesn't appear in Search Service Application in SharePoint Server 2019

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-search, sharepoint-2019

I have a problem in the search service. In my develop server, I can get a property which is a metadata column. I have some rules to exclude contents and include others.

My problem is when I try to do the same in a preproduction server, which have a ssl certificate (I'm not sure if it's a problem or not)
[image: PreProduction rules]

The config of this rules is in the below image:
[image: Configuration]

Anyone knows what's the problem? I have active the metadatanav feature in each spweb in the site collection.

Thanks in advance.

Active the metadatanav feature.
Completed crawl with a sharepoint content source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to have crawled properties after a crawl, you need **at least one item saved** in a list. If the property is linked to a page, you need to publish the page as well. With no data (for example when creating a new list), you will not get crawled properties in the search service application.

Comment: I had problem with the hosts file and I though I was working in the correct site, but it wasn't. So I was watching other site where I updated the files with metadata content in the column. Thanks for all!